# I removed another Mac's HD and reformatted it on disk utility, now it just shows blinking folder

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, disk-utility, ssd

So I removed a 2015 Macbook Air's HD from the computer and then using an OWC tool, I plugged it into my Macbook Pro and then erased it completely using Disk Utility. When I plugged it back into the Macbook Air, it goes dark and shows a blinking folder with a question mark. How can I fix this? I can't find any info online with this... I have Mac OS Mojave

Answer (score 0):

Blinking folder with a question mark means it can't find the startup folder, because there's nothing on the disk.

Disk should be formatted as APFS, with a scheme of GUID partition map. Reinstall it in the MacBook and boot while holding down option, command, and R at the same time. This will boot into internet recovery using a downloaded recovery image of the latest supported version of macOS your Mac can handle (10.14.3).

When it finally boots into the recovery menu, you can select the option to install macOS and follow the prompts to install macOS.

Comment: Or, if you make a bootable Mojave USB stick, make sure you formatted it APFS first,  then when you start your computer , holding down  Option, the boot loader will recognize your USB stick.